# How to populate the modified_by with the user_id of who made the update to the record using laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, traits

When using Laravel 5.1, I am trying to create an Observer that will automatically update the following 3 columns

1. created_by: populate when the record in created "never update this again"
2. modified_by: populate a new value every time a record is modified
3. purged_by: populate a value when a record is soft deleted.

I understand that Eloquent will automatically update the date time stamp (created_by, updated_at, removed_at) but I need to update the user_id that made the change.

I was advised to use Observer and a trait to handle this. Here is what I have done

1) created an observer class called "ModelSignature" located in `app\Observers\ModelSignature.php` and this is it's content

```
<?php 

namespace App\Observers;

class ModelSignature {

    protected $userID;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->userID =  Auth::id();
    }


    public function updating($model)
    {
        $model->modified_by = $this->userID;
    }


    public function creating($model)
    {
        $model->created_by = $this->userID;
    }


    public function removing($model)
    {
        $model->purged_by = $this->userID;
    }

}
```

I then created a new Trait called "RecordSignature" located in `app\Traits\RecordSignature.php` and contains the following code

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use app\Observers\ModelSignature;

trait RecordSignature
{

    public static function bootObservantTrait()
    {
        static::observe(new ModelSignature() );
    }
}
```

Finally, in my "Account" model located on "app\Models\Account.php" I use it like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\industry;
use App\Traits\RecordSignature;
use App\Traits\TrimScalarValues;


class Account extends Model
{
    use RecordSignature, TrimScalarValues;
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
    */
    protected $table = 'accounts';

    protected $primaryKey = 'account_id';

    const CREATED_AT = 'created_on';

    const UPDATED_AT = 'modified_on';

    const REMOVED_AT = 'purged_on';


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
    */
    protected $fillable = ['client_id','account_name', 'company_code', 'legal_name', 'created_by','modified_by','instrucations'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
    */
    //protected $hidden = ['account_id', 'remember_token'];


    protected $guarded = ['account_id'];

    /**
     * Get the industry record associated with the account.
    */
    public function industry()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(industry, industry::primaryKey);
    }

    public function pk(){

        return $this->primaryKey;
    }

}
```

The problem is that the methods `updating()`, `removing()` and `creating()` are not populating the userId as expected. It seems that the fields are being ignored or the methods are not being fired!

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a Laracasts subscription?

Comment: you need to create the boot for this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to get rid of your ModelSignatures Class and change your trait to something like:

```
trait RecordSignature
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::updating(function ($model) {

            $model->modified_by = \Auth::User()->id;
        });

        static::creating(function ($model) {

            $model->created_by = \Auth::User()->id;
        });
        //etc

    }

}
```

---

**Update**:

There are many packages nowadays that will handle this sort of thing for you. One that I currently use quite a bit is [Laravel Auditing](http://www.laravel-auditing.com/) which will not only keep track of who performed a task but also any changes to the row as well.

Comment: Upvote for Laravel Auditing package recommendation. It looks to be excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use venturecraft revisionable package with this upgrade https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-revisionable-upgrade

Everything will work out of the box, you just need to use 2 traits, you can do much more that get info who edited model, you can get info who edited particular column, even particular value and much more...

Answer (score 1):

step 1: make trait

```
namespace App\Traits;

use App\Observer\ModelObserver;

trait ObservantTrait
{

    public static function bootObservantTrait()
    {
        static::observe(ModelObserver::class);
    }

}
```

step 2: make observer

```
<?php

namespace App\Observer;

use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Config\Repository;
use Request;

class ModelObserver
{

    public $userID;
    protected $auth;
    protected $login_user;
    protected $ip;
    protected $user_agent;

    public function __construct(AuthManager $auth, Repository $config)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->login_user = $auth->guard($this->auth->getDefaultDriver())->user();
        if (isset($this->login_user->id)) {
            $this->userID = $this->login_user->id;
            $this->ip = Request::ip();
            $this->user_agent = Request::header('user-agent');
        }
    }


    public function updating($model)
    {

        $model->updated_by = $this->userID;
        $model->ip = Request::ip();
        $model->user_agent = Request::header('user-agent');

    }

    public function creating($model)
    {

        $model->created_by = $this->userID;
        $model->ip = Request::ip();
        $model->user_agent = Request::header('user-agent');

    }

    public function deleted($model)
    {

        $model->deleted_by = $this->userID;
        $model->ip = Request::ip();
        $model->user_agent = Request::header('user-agent');
        $model->save();

    }

}
```

step 3: user trait in model

```
use ObservantTrait;
```