# laravel watching relational data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relational-database

I am building a notification system for my application at the moment, I have notifications in their most basic form working, but I am struggling to get notifications work that need to be triggered by pivot data being changed.

Example:

I have a project model that has relationship like so,

```
public function projectmanager() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'project_managers');

}
```

So a project belongs to many users, the data is stored in the project_managers table the structure of which looks like this,

```
|-----------------------|---------------------|----------------------|
|         ID            |      PROJECT_ID     |       USER_ID        |
|-----------------------|---------------------|----------------------|
|         1             |         850         |           85         |
|-----------------------|---------------------|----------------------|
|         2             |         850         |           67         |
|-----------------------|---------------------|----------------------|
|         3             |         850         |           91         |
|-----------------------|---------------------|----------------------|
```

So in this example the project "850" has 3 project managers that all relate to a user. I have no problem getting the data of this, I can find who user 91 is etc etc.

My problem comes when I want to add or remove a project manager, the notification system that I trying to build requires that project managers are notified when a new project manager is created, and they are told who that project manager is.

Currently I add/remove project managers like this, in my projectController.php

```
if(is_array(Input::get('project_manager')) ){

    $managers = Input::get('project_manager');
    if( empty($managers) ){
       $project->projectmanager()->detach();
    } else {
        foreach( $managers as $pm ) {
            $pm_id[] = $pm['id'];
        }
    }
}

if($project->save() ) {
    if(isset($pm_id) && Input::get('project_manager')) {
        $project->projectmanager()->sync($pm_id);
    }
}
```

So basically what I do at the minute is remove all the relational data and then add is all again.  Firstly is there a better way to do this? Secondly I want to know what data has been added and removed is this possible to do? I know you can put model observers on models, and get original and dirty and compare them, but you don't seem to be able to use observers on pivot tables?

Comment: Might be that boot could do something like this.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709390/how-to-populate-the-modified-by-with-the-user-id-of-who-made-the-update-to-the-r

Comment: Maybe [soft deleting](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#soft-deleting) could help?